# trying to remove item from vector and this error came out: C2676 binary '=='

Tags: vector, iterator, containers, constants

```
for (Node &i : myNodes){
 if (CheckCollisionPointCircle(Vector2{ (float)(GetMouseX()),(float)(GetMouseY()) }, Vector2{ (float)(i.X),(float)(i.Y) }, i.radient)) {

    auto index = std::find(myNodes.begin(), myNodes.end(), i);
    myNodes.erase(index);

    }
}
```

trying to remove a Node from vector of nodes if the CheckCollisionPointCircle() returns true

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (auto iter = myNodes.begin(); iter != myNodes.end();) {
            if (CheckCollisionPointCircle(Vector2{ (float)(GetMouseX()),(float)(GetMouseY()) }, Vector2{ (float)(iter->X),(float)(iter->Y) }, iter->radient)) {

                iter = myNodes.erase(iter);

            }
            else {
                ++iter;
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).